# Deleting Row by Object ID in Parse

Tags: javascript, html, parse-platform

I don't know what is wrong with my code. I am trying to delete a specific row by the object ID in Parse. Right now, it's giving me a "error" in the console. I am not sure how to fix it. Thanks!

```
var rowId = Parse.Object.extend("Assignment");
var queryRemove = new Parse.Query(rowId);
var obj = $(elem).parent();
queryRemove.get("$(elem).parent().attr('id')", {
  success: function(obj) {
    console.log(obj + " got it");
    obj.destroy({
      success: function() {
        console.log("Deleted!");
      },
      error: function () {
        console.log("Deleted fail!");
      }
    });
  },
  error: function(obj ,error) {
    console.log("error");
  }
});
```

Comment: What is in the console?

Comment: Literally it says "error"

Comment: Change console.log("error"); to console.log("error", obj, error); and try again. Hopefully there will be more detailed data about the error.

Answer (score 0):

From the console log it is obvious that `queryRemove.get` is failing as you see `error` handler processed.

According to [Parse Api reference](https://parse.com/docs/js/api/symbols/Parse.Query.html) you should be passing a string id to `query.get()`, so I suppose you've mistaken in the parameter. JQuery should be evaluated and `.get` should receive id of an element not a string `"$(elem).parent().attr('id')"` which is obviously not a good id

```
 queryRemove.get($(elem).parent().attr('id'), {
```

Also doesn't look like you can delete an item with `.get()`... Have analysed parse.com api before using it?